# Upper case in tips

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, localization, tips, russian-stackexchange

Please approve the same rules of writing titles in tips on ["Русский язык" Meta](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as they are on [the main site](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). In Russian, only the first letter in a title is capitalized.

Correct:
[image]

Incorrect:
[image]